# Click on advanceddatagrid having dataprovider as grouping collection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid, groupingcollection

I am creating tree structure using advanceddatagrid. The dataprovider is grouping collection whose source is arraycollection. This grouping collection is grouping the fields as specified and I am getting the right tree structure.

I have this type of tree structure

```
Client
      Fund
          Account
```

Whenever user clicks on any of these node there is click handler which is as follows:

```
          private function clickhandler(event:Event){

           var item:VO=event.currentTarget.selectedItem as VO
           Alert(item.ID);
          }
```

Where VO is a bean class whose fields are

```
  ID
  Name
```

When I click on Account node I am getting the right alert value(according to above function) but when I click on fund or client I am not getting value in alert. It says error as 
         Type error:#1009 cannot access the property

So here when I click on leaf node I am getting the data source value which are associated to that node but when I am clicking non leaf node I am not getting the data source values like (as in above function VO.ID and VO.Name). How to get it solved?

Second question:
Also I want to know that on which level user has clicked in the tree that is level 1(client) or level 2(fund) or level 3(account).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer and AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid 
itemRenderer="MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer"
groupItemRenderer="MyAdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer">
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

In classes MyAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer and MyAdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer create click handlers in this handlers set breakpoints and debug. I think it helps you understand nodes